# 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I'm trying to print all cars in stuff from this json:

```
{
    "stuff": [
        {
           "car" : 1,
            "color" : "blue"
        },
        {
            "bcarus" : 2,
            "color" : "red"
        }
     ], 
}
```

In my Serializer I access the data like this....

> stuff = self.context.get("request").data.stuff

But when I do the following...

```
        for item in stuff:
            print(item)
```

I get he error:

> 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Why do I get this error?
How can I access `stuff` in a `for loop`?

When I do `print(self.context.get("request").data.stuff)` I get `<built-in method items of dict object at 0x105225050>` which I assumed print the `stuff` instead.

Comment: How are you decoding your JSON string?

Comment: @HamZa I'm using Django Rest Framework's default json decoder. printing stuff gives ... ``<built-in method items of dict object at 0x105225050>``

Comment: Is `"stuff"` the actual key, or is it named something else in your real code? `"items"`, perhaps? Because you can't access dict entries with dot notation, and if you try that with a key named `'items'`, you'll get the `items` method, which is something completely unrelated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stuff` ends up a method of function so you would need to call it:

```
    for item in stuff():
        print(item)
```

Which based on your comment is the `dict.items`.

So you can unpack:

```
 for k,v  in stuff():
     print(k,v)
```

Or just call when you assign:

```
 stuff = self.context.get("request").data.stuff()

 for k,v  in stuff:
     print(k,v)
```

Comment: I see, right so I assume DRF converting this somewhere. That seems to make sense.

Comment: what does `print(self.context.get("request").data)` output?

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_dict={"Car1":"Audi","Car2":"BMW","Car3":"Audi"}

for x in my_dict.values:
   print(x)
```

> 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

This may be because `my_dict.values` is a function that is expecting empty   "()" or some value in it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but for me I had items as an object key which coincidentally references a python object method Object.items(), had to change the key name in my object

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I came here looking for a solution to the iteration problem and I actually happened to stumble on the solution after noticing smth missing in  the codes try adding () to the method for example

```
my_dict={Car1":"Audi","Car2":"BMW","Car3":"Benz"}
for x in my_dict.values():
    Print(x)
```

Comment: There are at least 2 syntax errors: it should be `"Car1"` and `print(x)`. Also you seem to be addressing another answerer ("PCB"), so please reference them in your answer. Alternatively, you can try to first find another way to get 5 reputation, so that you can earn the commenting privilege.